# Numbers in reference list shown without square brackets

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, natbib

I am using

```
\documentclass[smallcondensed,singlecolumn]{svjour3}  
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\harvarditem{Boriah et al}{2008a}{agr:one} 
Boriah S, Kumar V, Potter C, Steinbach M and Klooster S 2008 Land Cover Change Detection using Data Mining Techniques. TR 08-009: ~ 1-16
\end{thebibliography}
```

This gives the following result:

> Reference
>
> 1  Boriah S, Kumar V, Potter C, Steinbach M and Klooster S 2008 Land Cover
>   Change Detection using Data Mining Techniques. TR 08-009: 1-16

However, I am looking for:

> Reference
>
> [1] Boriah S, Kumar V, Potter C, Steinbach M and Klooster S 2008 Land Cover
>   Change Detection using Data Mining Techniques. TR 08-009: 1-16

I also used various `natbib` styles but could not find the solution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  A quick hint: if you indent lines of code by four spaces, they'll automatically be pretty-printed by the site's software.

Comment: How was the formatted bibliographic item created? Specifically, which bibliography style did you employ?

Comment: Incidentally, what reason do you have for wanting the numbered labels in the bibliography section to show up as `[1]`, `[2]`, etc rather than as `1.`, `2.`, etc? Is it some formatting requirement you have to adhere to?

Answer (score 2):

You can change `\@biblabel{#1}` from the default `#1.` to `[#1]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[smallcondensed,singlecolumn]{svjour3}  
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{[#1]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
  \harvarditem{Boriah et al}{2008a}{agr:one} 
  Boriah S, Kumar V, Potter C, Steinbach M and Klooster S 2008 Land Cover Change Detection using Data Mining Techniques. TR 08-009: ~ 1-16
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```